# how can I update a mysql record using a form with mutliple inputs but only update the inputs with values entered

Tags: mysql, syntax

so my problem is this, I have a 3 part form that is a service ticket, the 1st part of the form is filled out by the dispatcher and submitted to mysql, the technician then see's they have a ticket assigned to them via email and they pull up the search result for tickets assigned to them and they click on a link in the search result that displays the 2nd form for them to enter what they did and what material and labor there is, this 2nd part of the form is my issue it has multiple values that are similar such as item_qty1, item_qty2, item_qty3 and so on. When I use more than 1 value like item_qty1 in my UPDATE tickets SET query I get a syntax error. Also, I am well aware that my code is subject to sql injection and I will deal with that when I have a working form.  So here is my code:

```
<?php
// database connection //

include 'db_connect.php';



include 'data/var/variables.php';

//Writes the information to the database

    mysql_query("UPDATE tickets SET     work_performed = $work_performed,
                                        item_qty1 = $item_qty1,
                                        item_qty2 = $item_qty2,
                                        item_qty3 = $item_qty3,
                                        item_qty4 = $item_qty4,
                                        item_qty5 = $item_qty5,
                                        manuf_1 = $manuf_1, 
                                        manuf_2 = $manuf_2,  
                                        manuf_3 = $manuf_3, 
                                        manuf_4 = $manuf_4,
                                        manuf_5 = $manuf_5,
                                        part_number1 = $part_number1,
                                        part_number2 = $part_number2,
                                        part_number3 = $part_number3,
                                        part_number4 = $part_number4,
                                        part_number5 = $part_number5,
                                        part_description1 = $part_description1, 
                                        part_description2 = $part_description2, 
                                        part_description3 = $part_description3, 
                                        part_description4 = $part_description4,
                                        part_description5 = $part_description5, 
                                        part_price1 = $part_price1, 
                                        part_price2 = $part_price2, 
                                        part_price3 = $part_price3, 
                                        part_price4 = $part_price4, 
                                        part_price5 = $part_price5,
                                        price_extension1 = $price_extension1, 
                                        price_extension2 = $price_extension2, 
                                        price_extension3 = $price_extension3, 
                                        price_extension4 = $price_extension4, 
                                        price_extension5 = $price_extension5, 
                                        material_total = $material_total, 
                                        sales_tax = $sales_tax, 
                                        shipping_cost = $shipping_cost, 
                                        work_date1 = $work_date1,
                                        work_date2 = $work_date2,   
                                        work_date3 = $work_date3, 
                                        work_date4 = $work_date4, 
                                        work_date5 = $work_date5, 
                                        tech_name1 = $tech_name1, 
                                        tech_name2 = $tech_name2, 
                                        tech_name3 = $tech_name3, 
                                        tech_name4 = $tech_name4, 
                                        tech_name5 = $tech_name5, 
                                        cost_code1 = $cost_code1, 
                                        cost_code2 = $cost_code2, 
                                        cost_code3 = $cost_code3, 
                                        cost_code4 = $cost_code4, 
                                        cost_code5 = $cost_code5, 
                                        pay_rate1 = $pay_rate1, 
                                        pay_rate2 = $pay_rate2, 
                                        pay_rate3 = $pay_rate3, 
                                        pay_rate4 = $pay_rate4,
                                        pay_rate5 = $pay_rate5, 
                                        total_hours1 = $total_hours1, 
                                        total_hours2 = $total_hours2, 
                                        total_hours3 = $total_hours3, 
                                        total_hours4 = $total_hours4, 
                                        total_hours5 = $total_hours5, 
                                        hours_subtotal1 = $hours_subtotal1, 
                                        hours_subtotal2 = $hours_subtotal2, 
                                        hours_subtotal3 = $hours_subtotal3, 
                                        hours_subtotal4 = $hours_subtotal4, 
                                        hours_subtotal5 = $hours_subtotal5, 
                                        total_hours = $total_hours, 
                                        material_total = $material_total, 
                                        labor_cost = $labor_cost, 
                                        grand_total = $grand_total  WHERE `id` = '$id'"); 




mysql_affected_rows();

echo mysql_error();

?>
```

The code as it is wont post to the database, it displays the error:

> ﻿﻿You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' item_qty1 = , item_qty2 = , item_qty3 = ' at line 1

I was told I don't need apostrophe's or back ticks on my values so I removed them and still get the error. Now I changed my code a bit to remove any similar values, example I removed any value beyond value 1 so item_qty2, item_qty3 and so on I removed so I now have this code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `tickets` SET   `work_performed` = '$work_performed',
                                        `item_qty1` = '$item_qty1',
                                        `manuf_1` = '$manuf_1', 
                                        `part_number1` = '$part_number1',
                                        `part_description1` = '$part_description1', 
                                        `part_price1` = '$part_price1', 
                                        `price_extension1` = '$price_extension1', 
                                        `material_total` = '$material_total', 
                                        `sales_tax` = '$sales_tax', 
                                        `shipping_cost` = '$shipping_cost', 
                                        `work_date1` = '$work_date1',
                                        `tech_name1` = '$tech_name1', 
                                        `cost_code1` = '$cost_code1', 
                                        `pay_rate1` = '$pay_rate1', 
                                        `total_hours1` = '$total_hours1', 
                                        `hours_subtotal1` = '$hours_subtotal1', 
                                        `total_hours` = '$total_hours', 
                                        `material_total` = '$material_total', 
                                        `labor_cost` = '$labor_cost', 
                                        `grand_total` = '$grand_total'  WHERE `id` = '$id'");
```

This modified code works flawlessly everytime with no syntax errors and posts to the selected record every single time, but, this wont work for me, I need the additional values OR I need a way for the user to add additional fields to the form if they need to which would solve my problem of not having to enter a value in every field unless they have to. Also if anybody has any examples on how to compress this to make it more "functional" not so bulky I guess, that would be appreciated very much. Thanks!

Comment: have you used mysql_real_escape_string() for your post variables which calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

Comment: @sAnS no I haven't since the final version of this will be PDO I didn't consider that.

Comment: have you tried sqlite_escape_string() or PDO::quote()..

Comment: @sAnS no I haven't, I don't understand what you are driving to as my issue is the query is requiring me to input something in every value listed and I don't always need to add input something in every value. so if I only have 1 item to enter in the items field and leave item_qty2, item_qty3 and so on empty I get a syntax error unless I remove those values from the query.

Comment: you should use escape function to escape any unwanted character or code which causing the error as well as  immune to SQL injection in your sql statement..

Comment: @sAnS I originally thought it was unwanted character or code but after filling out the form completely and it submitted with no syntax error that told me it's not unwanted code or characters.

Answer (score 2):

to just optimize the code, what can be done is :

```
// define an array of column names and values got from input.
$column_names = array('column1' => $column1, 'column2' => $column2, .....);

// built an sql select clause
$select_clause = array();
foreach ($column_names as $cn => $cn_val) {
 if (!empty($cn_val)) {
   $select_clause = "{$cn} = {$cn_val}";
 }
}
// built proper query
$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET" . implode(',', $select_clause) . " table_name WHERE .....";

// continue with your stuff.
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see how it works, thanks for your assistance jospratik. I don't know what is wrong with this site but it's hit or miss with using @jospratik sometimes it works most of the time it doesn't!